# Can't customize the application switcher

Tags: shortcuts, customization

I'm trying to change the shortcut for switching applications from `Alt+Tab` to `Ctrl+Tab`, but changes in the `System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation` are being ignored. Even if I disable the `Switch applications` shortcut entirely, it still maps to `Alt+Tab`. At one point I had some keys remapped with `xmodmap`, but since then I have deleted that configuration and rebooted. My keyboard layout settings are all defaults. The OS is Ubuntu 12.04, with all software updated this afternoon.

It would also be nice to have the variation of application switching that includes one icon per window, instead of one icon per application, since I am frequently switching between windows of an application and would rather not wait for the switcher to realize I want a *different* window of the *current* application. My other Ubuntu 12.04 install has the application switcher that I like, but I'm not sure how to choose between them on this install (which was set up by my university department). Thanks if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to install the Compiz Settings Manager (aka ccsm) and play with the settings of the Unity / other switcher plugins. Unfortunately, ccsm can be dangerous and can make Compiz crash or disable all the plugins, so do that if you know what you are doing or are ready to deal such bugs.

Comment: Compiz has an even better app switcher that lets me choose any key binding. No more stretching for tab :-) Thanks!